# Invalid Procedure Call or argument in vbaExcel while Writing into sheet3

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Duplicate()

Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")    
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"    
Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Range A:", xTitleId, "", Type:=8)    
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Range B:", xTitleId, Type:=8)

For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1    
    rng1Value = Rng1.Value
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If rng1Value = Rng2.Value Then
            MsgBox rng1Value            
            Rng1.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            ws.Cells("A2") = rng1Value            
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: where are you getting your error ? what line ?

Comment: Hi, I was getting error at ws.Cells("A2") = rng1Value  this line, I had mentioned cells value like cell("A2"), I changed to cells(I,i+1) then it is writing into sheet3., thanks